# How to fix libiconv error on Mac?

Tags: macos, libiconv

I have uninstall port from Mac with this comand:

```
sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

Then when I use wget to download file,it shows me:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/wget
  Reason: Incompatible library version: wget requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

How to do?

※ Mac OS X 10.7.5

## Addition

When I run

```
otool -L $(which wget)
```

It gave me

```
/opt/local/bin/wget:
    /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.19.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgnutls.26.dylib (compatibility version 49.0.0, current version 49.3.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libtasn1.3.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.13.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcrypt.11.dylib (compatibility version 19.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgpg-error.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.7)
    /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.8.0)
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set. It can cause problems like these and is generally not needed and actively harmful on OS X (such as in this case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently you built and installed a copy of `wget` locally while you had `libiconv` installed from MacPorts so it dynamically links to that library which you've now removed.  If you want to remove all traces of MacPorts, you'll need to rebuild that copy of `wget`.

Otherwise, you could install a copy of `wget` with MacPorts which will also install all dependencies like `libiconv`.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port clean wget
sudo port install wget
```

Or, instead of `wget`, you could use `curl` which Apple supplies with OS X.

UPDATE: Based on your update, it appears you are using a MacPorts-installed `wget`.  Somehow you've managed to get the dependencies out of sync. (Why use `port -fp uninstall installed` ?)  Suggest you now try:

```
sudo port selfupdate     # if not run recently   
sudo port clean libiconv
sudo port upgrade --force libiconv
```

to force an upgrade of `libiconv` to the current version.

UPDATE [2014-12]: Revisiting this, the problem may also be due to an incomplete MacPorts port file that doesn't register the `wget` port dependency on `libiconv`.  I've [opened an issue](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/46159) about it.  [...] And the MacPorts project answers that this may be a result of not following the MacPorts migration instructions when upgrading to a new release of OS X; there is a [MacPorts problem hotlist entry for `libiconv` compatibilities here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist#libiconv-version).

In any case, what may work is to reinstall `wget` from source.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port -f uninstall wget
sudo port -s install wget
```

If that doesn't help, you may want to read [the migration instructions](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) and make sure you've re-installed all your ports after upgrading.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have do what you wrote.But unlucky saw the error again.When I run `port installed` to check libiconv,it is libiconv @1.14_0 (active).And when I run the curl command,got a same message:(

Comment: Thank you!I have try your method.But the result is the same.Maybe something wrong in my pc.But thank you all the same.

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct and does not solve the problem.

Comment: @AntonioSesto It's not clear from your comment what problem you are talking about. There are many different scenarios possible. If you are having a problem, suggest opening your own question and describing the exact situation you have.

Comment: The problem is exactly the one described in the question. I tried the commands of the accepted answer, with no success.

Comment: OK, thanks. See the additional update above and let us know if that works for you.