# Incompatible library version running EiffelStudio

Tags: macos, eiffel

I installed EiffelStudio like this:

1) Downloaded **Eiffel_15.12_gpl_98497-macosx-x86-64.tar.bz2** from official page.

2)

> cd /usr/local
>
> tar xvfj /**path**/Eiffel_15.12.tar.bz2

3)

> export ISE_EIFFEL=/usr/local/Eiffel_15.12
>
> export ISE_PLATFORM=macosx-x86-64
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ISE_EIFFEL/studio/spec/$ISE_PLATFORM/bin

Then I type "**ec**" to run the command-line compiler and this is the output:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /usr/local/Eiffel_15.12/studio/spec/macosx-x86-64/bin/ec
>
> Reason: Incompatible library version: ec requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5

Any solution?

PS: Im using OSX 10.11.4

PPS: When i run

> otool -L $(which ec)

I get

> /usr/local/Eiffel_15.12/studio/spec/macosx-x86-64/bin/ec:
>
> /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
>
> ...

**EDIT**: I found this link that helps me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016967/6273708

But know the error message is

> dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /usr/local/Eiffel_15.12/studio/spec/macosx-x86-64/bin/ec
>
> Reason: image not found
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: There are quite a few questions with similar issues for other tools running on OSX: [1](http://superuser.com/questions/736210/how-do-i-remove-an-old-version-of-iconv-on-which-other-software-depends-and-ot), [2](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29142), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301786/how-to-fix-libiconv-error-on-mac), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011995/libiconv-conundrum-requires-version-x-0-0-or-later-but-libiconv-2-dylib-provide). One of the most frequent solutions seems to be to check whether an environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set and to unset it.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov I saw that posts but the most of them, solve the problem using MacPorts but I dont have MacPorts installed now. I dont have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set